# How to put my boxplots belonging to different categories on different scales

Tags: r, graphics, scale, boxplot

Here is my dataset

```
structure(list(id_data = c("20", "63", "93", "156", "162", "177", 
"38_", "44_", "57_", "63_", "73_", "79_", "105_", "111_", "154_", 
"156_", "158_", "168_", "20", "63", "93", "156", "162", "177", 
"38_", "44_", "57_", "63_", "73_", "79_", "105_", "111_", "154_", 
"156_", "158_", "168_", "20", "63", "93", "156", "162", "177", 
"38_", "44_", "57_", "63_", "73_", "79_", "105_", "111_", "154_", 
"156_", "158_", "168_"), bras = c("Treatment 2", "Treatment 2", 
"Treatment 2", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 1", 
"Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", 
"Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", 
"Treatment 1", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 2", 
"Treatment 2", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", 
"Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", 
"Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2", 
"Treatment 2", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 2", "Treatment 2", 
"Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", 
"Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 1", 
"Treatment 1", "Treatment 1"), Progesterone = c(0.2, 0.21, 0.17, 
0.19, 0.2, 0.46, 60, 21.6, 40.73, 34.07, 25.5, 60, 38.5, 60, 
16.36, 48.7, 22, 32.73, 0.2, 0.21, 0.2, 0.25, 0.2, 0.46, 38.49, 
7.22, 60, 23.03, 12.8, 57.14, 2.36, 46.1, 10.1, 14.21, 1.38, 
33.58, 0.25, 0.4, 0.39, 0.3, 0.2, 0.96, 15.2, 7.55, 12.46, 6.68, 
12.8, 15.92, 0.62, 2.71, 10.14, 14.21, 1.38, 2.51), Period = c("Time 1", 
"Time 1", "Time 1", "Time 1", "Time 1", "Time 1", "Time 1", "Time 1", 
"Time 1", "Time 1", "Time 1", "Time 1", "Time 1", "Time 1", "Time 1", 
"Time 1", "Time 1", "Time 1", "Time 2", "Time 2", "Time 2", "Time 2", 
"Time 2", "Time 2", "Time 2", "Time 2", "Time 2", "Time 2", "Time 2", 
"Time 2", "Time 2", "Time 2", "Time 2", "Time 2", "Time 2", "Time 2", 
"Time 3", "Time 3", "Time 3", "Time 3", "Time 3", "Time 3", "Time 3", 
"Time 3", "Time 3", "Time 3", "Time 3", "Time 3", "Time 3", "Time 3", 
"Time 3", "Time 3", "Time 3", "Time 3")), row.names = c(NA, -54L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I made boxplots by Treatment and period

```
ggplot(mydata, 
       aes(x=Progesterone, y=bras,fill=bras ))+
  geom_boxplot()+coord_flip()+
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Period))
```

[image]

But the difference in the magnitude of the values between the two treatments is so great that the boxplots of treatment 2 are no longer visible. I don't want to do a logarithmic transformation or normalization but rather to make the scales of the two treatment groups different (while keeping the boxplots of the two groups side by side (as in the figures below)

[image]

Do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the `scale="free_y"` parameter of `facet_wrap`, which gives you this:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Period, y = Progesterone, fill = bras)) + 
    geom_boxplot() + 
    facet_wrap(~bras, nrow = 1, scale = "free_y")
```

[image]

However, **I don't recommend this**. A plot like this can look very misleading, since it's easy to overlook that the scales are different. I recommend that you plot all 6 on the same scale (as in your question), and then add a clearly labelled, separate "zoomed in" panel to show the relative distributions of Treatment 2.

Incidentally, I've tidied up your ggplot a bit - there's no need to `coord_flip()`, just assign the coordinates you want in the first place!

Comment: Thanks Ottie. But I want to have a boxplot of treatment 1 next to a boxplot of treatment 2 every time. I want to use faceting for the period

Comment: You really, really, really shouldn't plot two boxplots next to each other in the same plot area at different scales. There is no way of doing this in ggplot, and for good reason.